# How to use two sets of colormaps in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to plot two sets of data in the same figure while using independent colormaps for each dataset. I created two colormaps `cmap_blue` and `cmap_green` using `sns.choose_colorbrewer_palette('sequential')`, respectively. However, when I tried to plot the datasets using the following code, it seems the second `sns.set_palette()` overrides the first one, resulting the green gradients for both datasets.

```
sns.set_context('paper')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[2.5, 2.5])

ax.set_xlim(0,600)
ax.set_ylim(0,15)

sns.set_palette(cmap_blue)
ax.plot(time_prot60, SFT_prot60)
ax.plot(time_prot70, SFT_prot70)
ax.plot(time_prot80, SFT_prot80)

sns.set_palette(cmap_green)
ax.plot(time_buffer60, SFT_buffer60)
ax.plot(time_buffer70, SFT_buffer70)
ax.plot(time_buffer80, SFT_buffer80)

plt.grid(True)
plt.savefig('/content/gdrive/My Drive/SVG/prot.svg', format='svg', bbox_inches = 'tight')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `sns.set_palette` sets the default color cycle for matplotlib. But the color cycle is also a property of each `ax`. Therefore, `sns.set_palette` only has an effect on an `ax` that is created afterwards. In the question of the post, the `ax` was already created earlier, and already had its own color cycle.

So, to get the desired behavior, the palette has to be assigned explicitly to the `ax`. The function `ax.set_prop_cycle` does just that. Here is some code. Note that I renamed `cmap_blue` to `palette_blue` to make a distinction between a colormap (a function that outputs colors) and a palette (a list of colors).

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from cycler import cycler

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

palette_blue = sns.color_palette("Blues")
palette_green = sns.color_palette("Greens")

ax.set_prop_cycle(cycler(color=palette_blue))
for i in range(1, 4):
    plt.plot(np.linspace(0, 10, 100), 10 * i + np.random.normal(0, 1, 100).cumsum())
ax.set_prop_cycle(cycler(color=palette_green))
for i in range(4, 7):
    plt.plot(np.linspace(0, 10, 100), 10 * i + np.random.normal(0, 1, 100).cumsum())

plt.show()
```

[image]